# Ionic 2.0 List Edit - Prepopulate Alert Field

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm working on an editable list within my Ionic 2.0 application. I've got it 90% of the way there, but am stumped on something that is probably rather easy.

When the user clicks the edit button for a list item, it uses the following script to present an alert. However, I would like the current name of the list item to appear pre-populated within the alert's field when they're editing it. I cannot seem to figure out how to accomplish this.

Script:

```
editSupplier(supplier){
     let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Edit Supplier',
        inputs: [{
            name: 'title',
            value: // dynamic value should go here
        }],
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Cancel'
            },
            {
                text: 'Save',
                handler: data => {
                    let index = this.suppliers.indexOf(supplier);

                    if(index > -1){
                      this.suppliers[index] = data;
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    });

    prompt.present();       

}
```

Item Code:

```
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let supplier of suppliers">
        <ion-item>
            <h2 color="dark">{{supplier.title}}</h2>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item-options side="right">
          <button ion-button (click)="editSupplier(supplier)" color="attention">
            <ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon>
          </button>
          <button ion-button (click)="deleteSupplier(supplier)" color="danger">
            <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
          </button>
        </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I've figured this out. I added a reference to the parent group (suppliers) and then captured the index of the specific supplier like this:

```
let currentIndex = this.suppliers.indexOf(supplier);
```

I then replaced the 'value' line of the code with this:

```
value: this.suppliers[currentIndex].title
```

and Bob's your uncle, the alert field is pre-populated.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
editSupplier(supplier){
 let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Edit Supplier',
    inputs: [{
        name: 'title',
        value: this.supplier.title
    }],
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Cancel'
        },
        {
            text: 'Save',
            handler: data => {
                let index = this.suppliers.indexOf(supplier);

                if(index > -1){
                  this.suppliers[index] = data;
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});

prompt.present();       

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, this doesn't work. I've actually already tried a few variations on this solution. On build, it throws a Typescript error "Property 'supplier' does not exist on type 'SuppliersPage'."